# Can a bipolar EEG signal be converted to a monopolar (unipolar) one?

Tags: methodology, eeg, electrophysiology, signal-processing

I have bipolar EEG signal of Fpz-Cz of EEG sleep data which I have downloaded from physionet. I would like to have Fpz signal for my sleep study.

Is there any way I could convert a bipolar EEG signal to a monopolar (unipolar) EEG signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
As far as I can see - no you can't.

**Background**
In EEG systems, unipolar signals are measurements against a distant reference electrode, for example Fpz (Fig. 1). So suppose I have recorded *unipolar* EEG signals, say O1 and O2 against Fps, then I can obtain a bipolar measurement offline by subtracting O1-O2 (source: [Biopac](https://www.biopac.com/knowledge-base/bipolar-eeg/)).

However, if you start with a bipolar measurement, *e.g.* O1-O2, then you can never reduce those recordings back to O1-Fpz and O2-Fpz as the O1 and O2 signals are independent of Fpz.

Further, 'the' Fpz signal is non-existant, as an electrophysiological potential (and in fact *any* potential), is a potential *difference* between 2 points. There *is no* potential difference on one electrode.

<sub>PS. 
I am not proficient in **[principal component analysis](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/49)**, but I do know that by cross-correlating various electrode-pairs a source analysis can be done. Perhaps you could somehow extract the unipolar signal from bipolar signals, but I must say that a Google Scholar search using the search terms 'principal + component + analysis + eeg + bipolar + to + unipolar' did not yield any useful hits, at least at first glance.</sub>

[image]
<sup>Fig.1. EEG montage. source: [Kemp *et al*., 2003](https://www.edfplus.info/specs/edftexts.html)</sup>